# How flexible is the Skin of Proteus?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, magic-items, psionics

The [psychoactive skin](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/psionics-unleashed/equipment/psionic-items/universal-items/#TOC-Psychoactive-Skins) *"Skin of Proteus"* grants the ability:

> This psychoactive skin continually affects the wearer as the [metamorphosis power](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/psionics-unleashed/psionic-powers/m/metamorphosis/). While in a form other than his natural form, the wearer does not appear to be wearing the skin.

*Metamorphosis* can grant a wide variety of effects to the target.
Does this skin allow the wearer to change which of the potential *metamorphosis* effects is currently active when they activate it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Skin of Proteus* can do anything that *metamorphosis* can, but does not gain any special ability to change which *metamorphosis* effects are applied: those are continuous once the *skin* is applied, so you only get to make those choices once, when you put the *skin* on. You have to spend a standard action removing, and another standard action putting it back on, in order to change what *metamorphosis* changes are affecting you.

Comment: Y'know, I'd kind of expect the *skin* to be a bit more flexible for 84,000 gp. Can this answer explain how this conclusion was reached? (That is, I suspect most readers will read the *skin* as allowing the wearer to take a standard action at will to activate the *metamorphosis* power, each new activation subsuming the old.)

Comment: @HeyICanChan I agree, I would probably allow a single standard action to swap things. But I don’t see anything in the description of psychoactive skins or *skin of Proteus* in particular that would allow this? Not sure how to prove a negative.

Comment: O, I'm not expecting you to prove a negative; I am intimately aware of how hard that is! I'm asking if this answer can explain why this particular method is mandated *by the item* for changing the benefit of the *metamorphosis* effect, and, perhaps, if there's a workaround (e.g. wearing a second *skin*, activating it, then reactivating the *skin of Proteus* so at least the dude doesn't have to get nekkid to change the *skin* effect.)

Comment: @HeyICanChan The question is more concerned with the ability to choose different *metemorphosis* effects upon each activation of the skin. So, for that purpose, I am satisfied with this response. I think KRyan is correct, in that it will take 2 standard actions to change the current effect, because of the text: _"the same command thought causes the skin to shrink back down to its former size"_ indicating there is no way, as written, to re-activate an already-activated psychoactive skin.

Comment: @royalmurder That's cool, but I'm concerned that given this answer, an *even stricter* reading is possible: that the *skin*'s creator picks the *metamorphosis* benefit when the *skin*'s created, and putting on the *skin* — that is, activating it — can only ever yield that lone benefit!